# How to set up Github Octicons in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, frontend, octicons

I've installed bootstrap

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3'
```

then I downloaded octicons from https://github.com/github/octicons/
. after extracting, I copied `octicons` directory to `app/assets/stylesheets/`.
Then in `application.scss` I added this line:

```
@import "octicons/octicons.scss";
```

But still I cant get Octicons to work. What is the correct way to set it up for my application?

Comment: What's not working? Apart from the emoji not showing, do you see the CSS in your browser? Do you get 404s?

Comment: I don't get any error. I added  `<span class="octicon octicon-person"></span>` in a `html.erb` file, but I can't see this icon in my browser.

Comment: But you do see the CSS when you inspect that element? What about the network tab? Do you see the fonts/svg files loading? EDIT: I meant errors on the browser, not Rails.

Comment: Yes, I can see the CSS  when I inspect it. But in network tab I don't see any file loading.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant the html element. I can't see any CSS for Octicon in Styles tab. Also in network tab I don't see any font file loading after reloading the page.

Comment: Which folder did you copy again? It's either build or lib (build is compiled CSS, lib is the source SASS), but not the parent folder you clone from Github.

Comment: I downloaded this https://github.com/github/octicons/releases/download/v3.5.0/octicons.zip
there was only one folder in it called `octicons`

Comment: That won't work. That project is an npm package that compiles SASS to CSS. Rails doesn't integrate directly with npm packages. It can, however, use SASS or CSS directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [octicons-rails](https://github.com/torbjon/octicons-rails), instead of downloading and copying octicons manually which doesn't work with asset pipeline.

Like what the README says:

Add the following to your app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:

```
*= require octicons
```

Comment: `octricons-rails` hasn't been updated in a couple of years (or April 2018), so it currently fails with `railties >= 5.0`, there is an open PR to fix this, **if you know what you're doing because this is potentially harmful**: you can include it with `gem 'octicons-rails', github: 'mgi166/octicons-rails', branch: 'change-railties-dependency'`